# iPad local databases

Tags: ipad, sqlite, couchdb

What are the best local iPad databases?

CouchDB or SQLLite? Which is better?

What does Evernote use? What does Foursquare use?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know what databases Evernore or Foursquare use *on the iPad*.

SQLite is currently the "best" database for mobile because it is already included and it is so small and light-weight. SQLite is one back-end in the Core Data API (which is most likely what Foursquare and Evernote use).

However, CouchDB is also very light-weight but it is not yet easy to use on iOS. If/when it does become easier, it will be ideal for mobile because it supports local, offline operation and has built-in synchronization with the central database.

Comment: I agree SQLite is definitely the most supported at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing from these two requires more thoughts:

For couchdb, the db is document oriented. 
It also is using webservices(so you will have to handle these properly) and the basic CRUD is done via REST.

Pro:
If your app wants to replicate data to or from the outside world, couchdb handles this very easily and you have the ability to write [couchapps](http://couchapp.org/), basically webapps  running directly on the couchdbserver. These could be delivered as natve IOS apps, I assume, as it is now possible for Android: [link](http://arandomurl.com/2011/02/13/developing-with-couchdb-on-android.html)

I am not familiar with basic patterns about handling data in IOS, but using a "driver" to use couchdb should be evaluated as well: h[ttp://www.couchone.com/page/couchdb-drivers](http://www.couchone.com/page/couchdb-drivers)